# C code to Sync Flash Drives

Tags: c

Just as a learning experience, I'm trying to code the following problems in C.

> If two flash drives are inserted each having a folder (say,
>   Course_Notes), then they get synced. That is, data is copied from one
>   to the other and if there a file already exists, then the newer one is
>   retained.

I would do this in bash by:

```
#!/bin/bash
while $1
do
cp -ur /media/PD_1/Course_Notes /media/PD_2/Course_Notes
cp -r /media/PD_2/Course_Notes /media/PD_1/Course_Notes
done
```

How do I do this in C without too many `system` calls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the real world, you'd probably use something like `rsync` for this.

You're probably looking for the [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) family of functions to get size and modification date, along with `opendir()`/[`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html)/`closedir()` for directory listings. The standard way for copying a file itself is to open the source and destination, and write to the latter what you read from the former with the usual read and write functions.

Note also that the source code for GNU and BSD versions of the standard UNIX utilites, such as `cp`, is freely available. (likewise for `rsync`) You may want to read some of that source code to see what you may have missed in your own approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a programming Q&A site, you would use usual programming tools (instead of rewriting them yourself).

This sounds like a perfect application for a Distributed Version Control System. Some of the most popular choices today are [Git](http://git-scm.com) and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com).

Comment: I am aware of them. This is merely an exercise in coding. Dropbox serves my purpose as well. But I wanted something **offline** and automatic.

Comment: Git works just fine offline. Also, Git will detect when you make different changes to the same file on both flash drives, while your method will simply overwrite one set of changes.